# Mutual information equals conditional mutual information

Tags: interaction, conditional-probability, information-theory, mutual-information

Consider three random variables $X,Y,Z$. It is standard that $I(X,Y|Z)=0$ if and only if $X,Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$.
If instead we require $I(X,Y|Z)=I(X,Y)$, what do we get? What properties would have the probability distributions that satisfy such constraint?

Answer (score 6):

You are in luck: this is a well-studied quantity under a different name. This is equivalent to the [Interaction information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_information) or a measure of [synergy](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/23/37/11539.short) being equal to zero. Consider the quantity $S(X,Y,Z) = I(X,Y|Z) - I(X,Y)$. In [2](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/23/37/11539.short) this is identical to eq. 10 if you first re-write $I(X,Y|Z) = I(X, (Y,Z)) -I(X,Z)$, so that $S(X,Y,Z) =  I(X, (Y,Z)) -I(X,Z) - I(X,Y)$. This quantity can be positive, negative or zero. If it is zero, it means that the information that $Y$ and $Z$ have about $X$ is additive. If it is negative it means that the information that $Y$ and $Z$ have about $X$ is redundant, and if it is positive the information is synergistic (i.e., Y and Z together have information about X that can not be gleaned from either one individually).

The implications for the probability distributions that satisfy this constraint are a little more complicated. In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0307072.pdf), they relate the synergy score to maximum entropy distributions satisfying certain constraints. If this quantity is negative, it implies something about the existence of common ancestors according to this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.5720.pdf), but I don't think it has implications in your case.

Another way to look at this condition is using the Venn diagram [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information). Your condition is equivalent to the very center gray area having a zero (that's just the triple information/interaction information again).

Comment: Great, thanks! So what distributions have the property that the interaction information is zero? Can we find such a distribution with given constraints, as we do for maximal entropy?

Comment: This is interesting, although there is a large literature about detecting synergistic information or redundant information, the special case right in the middle seems to be neglected! I hope someone else chimes in with something more direct and concrete.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe the arxiv paper about max ent and "connected correlations" is all there is to it. Eq. 7 says that the probability distribution has to have a certain form as an exponential with pairwise functions of the variables only (i.e., no function of x,y, and z can appear).

Comment: In what they call the FM case, $I=-1$ but the probability distribution has only pairwise functions, so not every pairwise potential has zero interaction information. But does the viceversa hold, i.e. does $I=0$ imply only (up to) pairwise functions?